# [UIThreadSafeNode textInputView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios9

I'm getting below crash quite often in production environment in iOS9. It used to work fine in iOS8. I believe this is keyboard related and in the logs, every crash happened after the app goes to the background. But I couldn't reproduce. Any help is appreciated.

```
{
      "StackTrace" : [
        "#0  CoreFoundation                      0X00000001854C4F48 <redacted>()",
        "#1  libobjc.A.dylib                     0X000000019A013F80 objc_exception_throw()",
        "#2  CoreFoundation                      0X00000001854CBC5C <redacted>()",
        "#3  CoreFoundation                      0X00000001854C8C00 <redacted>()",
        "#4  CoreFoundation                      0X00000001853CCCAC -[NSKVONotifying__UIPopoverLayoutInfo setContentInset:]",
        "#5  UIKit                               0X000000018AF5D7E0 -[_UIKeyboardTextSelectionGestureController redisableEnclosingScrollViewNestedPinching]",
        "#6  UIKit                               0X000000018AF5C640 -[_UIKeyboardTextSelectionGestureController _cleanupDeadGesturesIfNecessary]",
        "#7  UIKit                               0X000000018AF60C58 -[_UIKeyboardBasedTextSelectionGestureController _cleanupDeadGesturesIfNecessary]",
        "#8  UIKit                               0X000000018AE64734 -[UIKeyboardImpl setTextSelectionControllerFromDelegate]",
        "#9  UIKit                               0X000000018AA85800 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:]",
        "#10 UIKit                               0X000000018AA7F0B8 -[UIPeripheralHost _reloadInputViewsForResponder:]",
        "#11 UIKit                               0X000000018AB68BB4 -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder]",
        "#12 UIKit                               0X000000018AB09FD4 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder]",
        "#13 UIKit                               0X000000018AC7B72C -[UIWebDocumentView resignFirstResponder]",
        "#14 UIKit                               0X000000018AC7B648 -[UIWebBrowserView resignFirstResponder]",
        "#15 UIKit                               0X000000018B14E2E8 -[_UIRemoteKeyboards keyboardChanged:shouldConsiderSnapshottingKeyboard:isLocalEvent:]",
        "#16 UIKit                               0X000000018B14E52C <redacted>()",
        "#17 FrontBoardServices                  0X000000018F10F7C4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext]",
        "#18 FrontBoardServices                  0X000000018F0F5D4C -[FBSWorkspace synchronizeSystemAnimationFencesWithSpinCleanUpBlock:]",
        "#19 UIKit                               0X000000018ACFC430 -[UIApplication _synchronizeSystemAnimationFencesWithSpinCleanUpBlock:]",
        "#20 UIKit                               0X000000018AD4EF84 <redacted>()",
        "#21 QuartzCore                          0X000000018A287B28 <redacted>()",
        "#22 QuartzCore                          0X000000018A24CDC4 <redacted>()",
        "#23 QuartzCore                          0X000000018A24CA08 <redacted>()",
        "#24 MediaToolbox                        0X0000000187DEACB4 <redacted>()",
        "#25 libdispatch.dylib                   0X000000019A82BDD4 dispatch_mig_server()",
        "#26 libdispatch.dylib                   0X000000019A8256A8 <redacted>()",
        "#27 libdispatch.dylib                   0X000000019A83C2BC <redacted>()",
        "#28 libdispatch.dylib                   0X000000019A827B9C <redacted>()",
        "#29 libdispatch.dylib                   0X000000019A82A868 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF()",
        "#30 CoreFoundation                      0X000000018547C1F8 <redacted>()",
        "#31 CoreFoundation                      0X000000018547A060 <redacted>()",
        "#32 CoreFoundation                      0X00000001853A8CA0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific()",
        "#33 GraphicsServices                    0X0000000190410088 GSEventRunModal()",
        "#34 UIKit                               0X000000018AAC0FFC UIApplicationMain()",
        "#35 Ambulatory                          0X00000001000B62B4 -[AppDelegate openChartSummaryAfterLoginWithPatient:andEncounter:]",
        "#36 libdyld.dylib                       0X000000019A8568B8 <redacted>()"
      ]
    }
```